# How to declare constants as distinct using the z3 c++ API

Tags: c++, api, z3

Giving for example: 
    context ctx;

```
sort type1 = ctx.int_sort();
sort type2 = ctx.bool_sort();

func_decl b1 = function("b1", type1, type2);

expr x = ctx.int_const("x");
expr y = ctx.int_const("y");
expr z = ctx.int_const("z");

solver s(ctx);
s.add(b1(x));
s.add(b1(y));
s.add(b1(z));
```

How can one declare x, y and z as distinct other than using: 
    s.add(not(x==y or x==z or y==z));
?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Z3 supports the `distinct` function, which in C++ is available as `expr expr::distinct(expr_vector const & args)`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please give me an example of its usage in relation with my previous example?

Comment: Suppose v is an ast_vector containing x, y, z, then expr c = distinct(v); creates a constraint that describes x, y, z must all be different.

Comment: Ok. Thanks.   for example:  expr_vector v(ctx);
    v.push_back(x);
    v.push_back(y);
    expr c=distinct(v);

Comment: In relation with my previous example, if we would like to have interactively the value given by the function b1 to some special constante (by reading the constant and searching its value by b1, 
e.g.,: std::cin >>constante;
std::cout <<  m.eval(b1(constante));). 
What must be the type of constante? Thanks.

Comment: It should be an int since b1 takes an int and returns a bool.